# Boomerang beacon called via GET instead of POST

Tags: boomerang

I took a freshly-cloned copy of the Boomerang library and ran `make` to produce the default `boomerang.js` script.

I copied that file, along with the following HTML document into a directory.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/boomerang.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
BOOMR.init({
  user_ip: "127.12.34.56",
  beacon_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/beacon",
  beacon_type: "POST"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello RUM</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I then served that out of host running on port 8008 and viewed the html file. When I check the access log, I see

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016:15:13:31 +0200] "GET /beacon?u=http%3A%2%2F127.0.0.1%3A8008%2Frum.html&v=0.9&...
```

That is, the Boomerang library is issuing a GET instead of POST and at a quick glance I can't figure out why. (The `/beacon` endpoint doesn't actually exist, so it throws a 404, but that is (I hope) beside the point). I'll take a closer look with dev tools, but has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: I'm guessing you're the person who posted on gitter as well.  Hope the answer there was sufficient.  In future, the github issues list is preferable to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes I am. It took a while reading the documentation to figure that out. SO was my first reflex.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will make that clearer.